# Sage: difference between load and attach

Tags: load, attachment, sage

I know that the main difference between 'load' and 'attach' in Sage is that the latter automatically reloads a file when it changes. My question: **is there any other difference?** Because if there is not a slowdown in the 'attach' performance, should not be always 'attach' preferred over 'load'?

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's a matter of preference.

You may prefer using load instead of attach if you are making lots of changes to your file.  If you have gotten used to saving your file very often, you might save it in situations when it has syntax errors in it (for instance, you stopped in the middle of a line and jumped to changing something else).  If you attached the file, Sage will immediately complain with a SyntaxError, which is distracting for no good reason.